# Add User to Saltstack for PAM and CherryPy

Tags: cherrypy, salt-stack, pam

I'm trying to get the SaltStack `salt-api` working...

I've added my `external_auth` configuration to `/etc/salt/master`

```
external_auth:
  pam:
    myuser:
      - .*
```

According to docs, this gives username `myuser` permission to run all modules on the minions.

I've also added this to `/etc/salt/master`:

```
rest_cherrypy:
  port: 8000
  ssl_crt: /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
  ssl_key: /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.key
```

I can successfully connect to `https://localhost/login:8000` but my question is, how do I add `myuser` and specify a password? How does `salt-api` know about `myuser`?

Answer (score 0):

You've specified [external PAM auth](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/eauth/index.html) which:
"respects the current PAM configuration in place, and uses the 'login' service to authenticate.". It means that:

This is just plain system user

In order to add/modify user you can simply:

```
useradd -r myuser
echo 'myuser:mypassword' | chpasswd
```